# Multiple Optional Parameters with ServiceStack.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I'm trying to implement a service with Multiple Optional Parameters using ServiceStack.Net

At the moment my route looks like this

```
Routes.Add<SaveWeek>("/save/{Year}/{Week}");
```

I want to support uris like this:

> /save/2010/12/Monday/4/Tuesday/6/Wednesday/7

ie Monday=4, Tuesday=6 and Wednesday=7

However I want the ability to ignore days i.e. the person calling the service can decide if they want to save each value for each day...

i.e. Like this with missing parameter values

> ?Monday=4&Wednesday=7&Friday=6

Of course one solution would be to have the following route and just pass 0 when I don't want to save the value.

```
Routes.Add<SaveWeek>("/save/{Year}/{Week}/{Monday}/{Tuesday}}/{Weds}/{Thurs}/{Fri}/{Sat}/{Sun}");
```

But..... is there a better way of achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When your Route requirements start to get too complicated it will eventually become easier just to add a wild card path so you can parse the rest of the querystring yourself. i.e. in this case since the first part of the querystring remains constant you can add a wild card mapping to store the variable parts of the querystring, i.e:

```
Routes.Add("/save/{Year}/{Week}/{DaysString*}");
```

ServiceStack will still populate the partial DTO with the **Year** and **Week** fields (as well any fields that were passed in the querystring). The remaining variable parts of the url is stored in the **DaysString** which you are then free to parse yourself manually. So the above mapping will be able to match urls like:

/save/2010/12/Monday/4/Tuesday/6?Wednesday=7

And populate the following variables in your Request DTO:

- Year: 2010
- Week: 12
- Wednesday: 7
- DaysString: Monday/4/Tuesday/6