# ServiceStack Request DTO with variable number of properties

Tags: servicestack

I'd like to create an endpoint that is the front end for a query service and I'd like to support a scenario where any number of arguments can be passed into the service via querystring parameters.

This is the sort of URL I want:

`/queries/MyQuery?argument1=value&arg2=value`

The DTO object structure itself is fairly straightforward (a property such as `Dictionary<string, object>`) but I'm stuck on what the route should look like. Is this possible via the RouteAttribute or do I need to go another direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good answer that explains [Routing in ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12165439/85785).

Only the **PathInfo** is apart of the Route, the Request DTOs on all routes/services are also automatically populated based on the Request Params on the QueryString/FormData etc.

So if you know what the QueryString is going to be you can just add it as properties on the Request DTO and they will get automatically populated.

If you don't know what they are, but you still want access to the QueryString you can get it from the `base.Request` property in your Service, e.g:

```
 class MyServices : Service 
 {
     public object Get(MyQuery request) 
     {
        foreach (var entry in base.Request.QueryString) {
            ...
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: The second part is what I was missing. I'd been implementing IService<T> directly.

Comment: Note: You can still get access to it from your `IService<T>` if your service also implements `IRequiresRequestContext`. But I would still recommend using one of the supplied base classes unless you have a reason not to.