# REST Routing in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I just start to learn REST and ServiceStack and there's something about `Route` that I just can't quite understand. For example if we take the very basic HelloWorld example from GitHub tutorial and re-write it to return collection of `User` objects. Here is example:

```
public User
{
    public string Name;
    public string Address;
    public int Age;
}


// Hello - request object without [Route] attribute
public class Hello
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse
{
   public IEnumerable<User> Result {get;set;}
}


public class HelloService : Service
{
   public object Any(Hello request)
   {
       return new HelloResponse { // Collection of User object };
   }
}
```

now everything working right and no problems here. But now I want to add another routing url like:  `/Hello/{name}/Address`

Actually this call (GET) to this url will return a single `User` selected by `Age` parameter.  How I can do this ?  Should I add another `Service` ? And if the url will be:

`/Hello/{name}/{age}/Address`

It seems I don't understand something.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this earlier answer for details about [Routing in ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12165439/85785). The Smart Routing section in [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) explains further options and different precedence.

There are a few problems with your example. First ServiceStack text serializers only support **public properties** so you need to change your User Model to use public properties instead of fields, e.g:

```
public User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Next, [Interfaces on DTOs are a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785) as there's no good reason for it. They're still supported but you can end up with undesirable results. Use a concrete collection like a `List<T>` which provides more utility, e.g:

```
public class HelloResponse
{
    public List<User> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Also the routes **should match** the property names on your DTO **exactly**, they are case-insensitive when matching against the Request Path, but they need to map to an exact property name, e.g:

```
/Hello/{Name}/{Age}/Address
```

Comment: Thanks for the asnswer but it seems that I misunderstand the `Route.Add` function. Please correct me if I wrong! The schema for `Route.Add` is:  Route.Add<request-DTO-object-type-here>("/<DTO-object-name>/{DTO-field-name}/{DTO-field-name}")   . On client side it serialized to full DTO object with fields set as in url and deserialized on server in function that has parameters as DTO type and actual HTML verb (POST/GET) ? Is that generally correct ?

Comment: `Route.Add<TRequestDto>()` and `[Route]` attribute are exactly the same. i.e. they both Apply to a Request DTO but the route itself can be any text literal you want to match. The variables in the Route need to map to the Request DTO fields.