# Mapping value of a parameter in querystring to a DTO property

Tags: routes, servicestack

I am trying to find a way to get the value in this querystring to my DTO object.

```
example.org?code=abc
```

I have to map value of code to AuthorizationCode property (parameter names don't match either). I tried routing like this but it doesn't work.

```
[Route("?code={AuthorizationCode}", "GET")]
public class Registration
{
    public string AuthorizationCode { get; set; }
}
```

Since this is a callback URL, I don't have a chance to change it. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read this earlier [answer on ServiceStack's Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12165439/85785). Routes should only contain the `/path/info` they should never contain the queryString which are automatically able to populate all Request DTOs by themselves.

If you just have a code property in your DTO like:

```
[Route("/registration", "GET")]
public class Registration
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

You can already populate it with: `/registration?code=abc`.

Otherwise if you want to insist having different names for queryString and DTO, you can try creating an Alias by annotating your DTOs as a `[DataContract]`:

```
[Route("/registration", "GET")]
[DataContract]
public class Registration
{
    [DataMember(Name="code")]
    public string AuthorizationCode { get; set; }
}
```

Either way you can always access the QueryString directly in your services or filters:

```
public MyService : Service 
{
    public object Post(Registration request) 
    {
        var code = base.Request.QueryString["code"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I suppose I can introduce another segment to my callback URL but other callbacks will only be different by the parameters they pass in querystring. Should I use same Route attribute on all DTOs and decide which one to use in Get/Post handlers?

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you update the question to provide an example or a link to a gist what you're trying to do?

Comment: So, the query string isn't case-sensitive for param names?!

Comment: It's up to the underlying ASP.NET/HttpListener Request, ServiceStack [adds no overhead, just passes it through](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Extensions/HttpRequestWrapper.cs#L153)