# Service Stack Routing - Route Table?

Tags: servicestack

So how is routing managed, I see a bunch of attributes used on classes.  So is there no central MVC or REST route table in ServiceStack?

Comment: You can use the [Fluent API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing).  Also in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164201/servicestack-routing-does-not-work-with-querystring/12165439#12165439)

Comment: thanks I didn't see that yet, I figured there had to be routing tables you could create but I was seeing a lot of routing attributes on the service methods which makes me think that would be a bad way to go as you'd have a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) supports Route attributes and Fluent configuration of Routes which are just different ways of achieving the same result, both explained on the [Routing wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing).

The [Routing Metadata](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#routing-metadata) is available internally in ServiceStack via `EndpointHost.Config.Metadata` and externally via the `/operations/metadata` route. A link to the **Operations Metadata** page is displayed at the bottom of the `/metadata` when in ServiceStack is in DebugMode.

Comment: does it make sense to use a bit of both?  Lets say I have an ASP.NET MVC project and I want to use both the MVC route table and also at times the ServiceStack route table.  They're 2 different conventions but is it first off possible to use a mix of both and also does it even make sense to do so?  I'm just thinking we may want to still use the ASP.NET MVC route table but also your built-in hashed route table..I'm just thinking at the moment is all.

Comment: There's not a whole lot about routing in the docs other than thank link you provide in terms of talking about setting up or if you should or can use both routing systems, etc