# ServiceStack "Handler for request not found" when it is working for dozens of similar DTOs

Tags: servicestack

I have been using ServiceStack for months now.  It has been working great for awhile and I've used many advanced approaches and Redis integration.  I have a license, so my issue is not regarding a license issue, but I wonder if it is related.  It almost looks like I have hit a maximum of DTO or paths, but I do not get any such error, simply the "Handler for request not found".  So here is my question: how can you debug and isolate this error?  I have read all the posts I can find on proper formats for DTO and DTO filters and I have been doing this long enough that I can see nothing wrong in this regard.  Identically styled DTO's and paths work, but new ones fail, or so it seems.  Even if I find there is something I am doing wrong in my DTO setup, the question remains, is there a way to debug this?  Of course, finding what I'm doing wrong, if that is the case, is the first question.

Here is my code, AppHost first:

```
.Add<UsersCredentials>("/userscredentials", "GET")
.Add<UserCredential>("/userscredentials", "DELETE")
.Add<UserCredential>("/userscredentials/{UserName}", "POST PUT DELETE")
.Add<UserCredential("/userscredentials/{UserName}/(Permissions}/{System}/{ParamSet}/{Instrument}/{Interval}", "POST PUT DELETE")
```

DTO:

```
[Route("/userscredentials", "GET")]
public class UsersCredentials : IReturn<UsersCredentials>
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Permissions { get; set; }
    public string System { get; set; }
    public uint ParamSet { get; set; }
    public string Instrument { get; set; }
    public uint Interval { get; set; }
}    //Request DTO

[Route("/userscredentials", "DELETE")]
[Route("/userscredentials/{UserName}", "POST PUT DELETE")]
[Route("/userscredentials/{UserName}/(Permissions}/{System}/{ParamSet}/{Instrument}/{Interval}", "POST PUT DELETE")]
public class UserCredential : IReturn<UserCredential>
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Permissions { get; set; }
    public string System { get; set; }
    public uint ParamSet { get; set; }
    public string Instrument { get; set; }
    public uint Interval { get; set; }
}    //Request DTO
```

And Service:

```
// UsersCredentials
public class UsersCredentialsResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } //Where Exceptions get auto-serialized
}

public class UsersCredentialsService : Service
{
    private bool init = false;


    public object Get(UsersCredentials request)
    {

        return (request);
    }

    public object Post(UserCredential request)
    {

        return request;

    }

    public object Put(UserCredential request)
    {

        return request;

    }

    public void Delete(UserCredential request)
    {
    }
}
```

I use "POSTMAN" for debug and send this as a POST:

```
    http://sun:1300/userscredentials/a?format=json
```

It works.  Then I send as POST:

```
    http://sun:1300/userscredentials/a/b/c/1/d/2?format=json
```

and get, "Handler for Request not found: Request.HttpMethod: POST Request.PathInfo: /userscredentials/a/b/c/1/d/2 Request.QueryString: format=json Request.RawUrl: /userscredentials/a/b/c/1/d/2?format=json"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Routing:

You shouldn't be defining the routes in the AppHost using the `.Add<T>` method **as well as** using `[Route("/route", "METHOD")]` on the DTO.

You only need to use **one method**. So this may cause conflict, and certainly extra maintenance. I recommend using just the latter, of the `Route` attribute. So remove the `Add` rules from your AppHost as they are covered by the DTO routes.

You should also read the [routing documentation here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing), and [this post about routing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12165439/1295344) also.

## Typo:

You have a typo in your route code. You have an incorrect bracket `(` instead of `{`:

```
(Permissions}
```

Should be:

```
{Permissions}
```

## Metadata

An excellent place to check the service is defined properly is by checking the applications Metadata feature. This is enabled by default, so you can do this by adding `/metadata` to your server url. i.e.

```
http://localhost:{port}/metadata
```

[image: Meta data]

You can see an [example metadata page here](http://servicestack.net/metadata)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  I missed that you don't need to put it in both AppHost and the DTO method to define your routes.  I can swear it did not work for me at one point to have it in only the one place, but now I'm thinking I was simply learning about routes and something else threw me off.  But that typo was the real killer (the bracket being wrong).  In the end it is a good thing it happened as I never realized about the AppHost redundancy.  This also explains another problem I was seeing, which was double routes for the same thing.  Thanks again, I lost 10 hours on this!

Comment: To be clear about the "double routes", I was looking at the metadata, and the route was listed there.  The bad bracket was not obvious, but the fact that I had two routes to the same destination was.  I puzzled over this but could not debug it.  For others sake though, it did not cause a conflict to have it twice, it was just the bad bracket.  I would strongly suggest that ServiceStack, or someone helping their project think about a syntax checker for this situation.  I know it was my error, but its an easy one to make.