# Passing additional parameter not contained on DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, servicestack, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a REST ServiceStack Route.Add declaration like this
`Routes.Add<MyDTOObject>(/servicename/{property1fromDTO});` but I need to pass an additional String value that is not defined on MyDTOObject class declaration.

Is it possible to pass something like this 
`Routes.Add<MyDTOObject>(/servicename/{property1fromDTO}/{additionalString});`
 and retrieve it on my `OnGet(MyDTOObject request){...}` method implementation?

Currently I'm only able to get values from `request` for attributes that are defined on the `MyDTOObject` class declaration as specified by the Annotation used for the `Routes.Add`.

On my Service code I have this:
`public override object OnGet(MyDTOObject request)`
`{ ...`

`request.property1fromDTO //get value`

`...}`

but I cannot do this:
`request.additionalString //get the value`

because Visual Studio doesn't recognizes it as a property of type `MyDTOObject`

Help will be appreciated since I'm fairly new to ServiceStack and RESTful services. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve but you can use a [wildcard at the end to absorb multiple paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781126/85785), e.g:

```
Routes.Add("/save/{Year}/{Week}/{DaysString*}");
```

Which will populate the known variables and leave the rest in `DayString` for you to parse manually. See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781126/85785).

You can ignore the additional path with the `{ignore}` keyword, e.g:

```
Routes.Add<MyDto>(/servicename/{property1fromDTO}/{ignore});
```

You also have full access to the request from inside a Service with `base.Request`, e.g:

```
base.Request.QueryString["param"];
base.Request.PathInfo
base.Request.RawUrl
```

*Note: it looks like you're using the old API (i.e. *OnGet*). I recommend inheriting from `Service` so you can use the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) as the Old API was removed in the next v4 of ServiceStack.*

Comment: @DevJE if it's not typed, it's not on the DTO - use the `base.Request` to access additional properties of the underlying request (as shown in my answer). Note: you're using the **Old API** if you're new you should be using the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api), since the Old API was removed in v4.

Comment: It's a project some other person built; was not my decision.